# Can you expand an environment variable in a file while copying via an RPM spec file?

Tags: shell, sed, rpm, cp

This may be a little awkward question and I don't know if this is possible.

The question is:

#### `file.txt`

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello, ${MY_USERNAME}");
   }
}
```

I want to club the above file in one of my rpm. The .spec file for the RPM creation will have only below action for this particular file.

`cp /root/template/file.txt /home/gaur/hello.java`

Is it possible without using some logic in .spec file (for rpm creation), that when I copy it from `/root/template/file.txt` to `/home/gaur/hello.java`, the value in file.txt i.e. `${MY_USERNAME}` gets replaced by `gaur`? (by putting something in this `file.txt`?

Note: I know I can use `sed` in the `.spec`, but I am just curious to know if we can have some logic inside `file.txt`.

Note: The template file in `/root/template` can be in any language including shell, Python, Perl etc.

Comment: Can you make your question a little more clear?  It sounds like you are asking "can I make `cp` perform variable substitution?", to which the answer is of course, no, it doesn't do that, it just copies file.  But maybe you are asking something else?

Comment: Can you rephrase "want to club the above file" because otherwise we're making assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the alternatives, a better approach would be to generate the spec-file itself (using sed, or whatever tool), because your rpm is apparently used to generate data for a pathname which might change (a username).

For instance, your rpm might be used to create a user with a sample program.  The username would be the parameter substituted in the sample program, as well as the parameter passed to `useradd`.

Generating the spec-file would also let you generate the `%files` section of the rpm, making it match the actual pathname.

Relying on an environment variable would be awkward:

- inheriting it from the environment of the installing (root) user might not provide the value you needed, since `sudo` trims most environment variables, and
- using an environment variable as such within the script in the spec-file is usually unnecessary since it handles shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure what you are asking for is impossible, because the RPM would provide compiled Java bytecode, while you are asking to modify the source. For that, like you said, `sed` or similar would be the way to go.